# Problem with loading a bitmap with the LoadImage() function

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, bitmap, windows-ce

I develop an application in C++ on Windows CE 2013.

I want to load a bitmap from file and show it on-screen.

The problem is the `LoadImage()` function always returns `NULL`.

```
HDC hdcOkno;
hdcOkno = GetDC(hWnd);
HBITMAP hbmObraz;
hbmObraz = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"C:\\Users\\tykab\\OneDrive\\Pulpit\\bitmapy\\background_blue.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, NULL);
BITMAP bmInfo;
GetObject(hbmObraz, sizeof(bmInfo), &bmInfo);
BitBlt(hdcOkno, 50, 50, bmInfo.bmWidth, bmInfo.bmHeight, hdcOkno, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: Check the results of all those function calls with [`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms960717(v=msdn.10)).

Comment: Function return error 1814

Comment: It is ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND, but path that I defined is correct.

Comment: @BartłomiejTyka That is because you are not specifying the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag, so your string gets interpreted as a resource name instead of a file path, and the resource name you are specifying really does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Since you are working on Windows CE platform, `LoadImage()` can not load bitmaps from files.  You should use [`SHLoadDIBitmap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/aa453720(v=msdn.10)) instead.

**Original Answer**:

From the [`LoadImage` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea):

> `name`
>
> Type: `LPCTSTR`
>
> ...
>
> **If the `hinst` parameter is NULL and the `fuLoad` parameter omits the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` value, the `lpszName` specifies the OEM image to load**...
>
> ...
>
> If the `fuLoad` parameter includes the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` value, `lpszName` is the name of the file that contains the stand-alone resource (icon, cursor, or bitmap file). Therefore, set `hinst` to NULL.

You are not specifying the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag in the `fuLoad` parameter.  The last parameter should be set to the following when loading a file:

```
LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE
```

As mentioned in the comments, it's always a good idea to check `GetLastError()` on errors.

Comment: Unfortunately for WindowsCE platform this flags are unavaliable